# rotate imagebutton around itself without moving it

Tags: android, android-animation, image-rotation

Hello I am working with `ImageButton` for android application

the button in xml looks like that :

```
[LEFT][LEFT]
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
```

I am trying to rotate it with this code

```
RotateAnimation ra =new RotateAnimation(1000, 90);
ra.setFillAfter(true);
ra.setDuration(0);
prevBut.startAnimation(ra);
```

The `ImageButton` does rotate - but it moves a bit to the left after rotation.

> I am interested of rotating the ImageButton only without moving it to
>   the side is that possible ?

Comment: try `RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5f, Dimension.RelativeToSelf, 0.5f);
`

Comment: hey did you try the answer i posted ?

Comment: Yes i did but Eclipse doesnt recognize Dimension, he is asking me to create local varible, how could i fix that ?

Comment: Yes it Does only that i need to write  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF
instead of Dimention.RELATIVE_TO_SELF
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

ImageView image = findViewById(my image);
image.setAnimation(rotate);
rotate.setDuration(1000)
rotate.start();
```

Comment: thanks a lot  that solved my problem.
using Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF